# How to compare one table's column against another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on merging two tables and I am trying to verify if there are any duplicates across two columns. I suppose I'm looking for a Query that lats me compare every value of the columns much like:

```
WHERE 'column1' = 'value1'
```

but in place of 'value1' it'd be 'column2'

```
WHERE 'column1' = 'column2'
```

There would also be a bit of a function to count any duplicates.

Does anyone know if there's any function like this? So far I've drawn up blanks.

Cheers!

Doesn't matter - seems yesterday I made a bit problem over nothing. Thanks for getting my mind whirring. I'll Update with the result when I get some output.

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE column1 != column2`? Your question is unclear, you should add some sample data and a desired end result.

Comment: Is `column2` from your second table? How do you merge these tables?

Comment: Ah this is just me trying to get my head round things. I've been working off a Spreadsheet, converted some old data into a nice new relational database and now I've been told I have to merge that database with another one. I just wanted to check what form of duplication was there in some license key values. This spreadsheet has been made in parallel with this other system and I just don't kow whats unique and what isn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something similar to:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE A INNER JOIN TABLE B ON (//Whatever condition you need)
WHERE A.column1=B.column2
```

Comment: Yeah looks like being ill has gotten on me a bit. had a quick play about and wondered why the hell i didn't try a join yesterday! Just got a error to say that the types don't match but that's something I'll have to work around

Answer (score 0):

You can try both but i prefer the first example

```
select count(*)   
from table1 as t1   
inner join table2 as t2   
on (values you need to compare)
```

or

```
select count(*)   
(  
from select *   
from table1 as t1   
where column is exists(select * from table2 as t2 on (values you need to compare))  
) as table
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The tables / databases I'm joining are different languages Latin1_General_CI_AI and SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS respectively. Changing the language has just told me it' looking for a stored procedure "w " The fun never ends!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
INTERSECT
SELECT column2
FROM table2
```

This will give you all the result where they are the same

Refer to : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with  a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to get comparison of both tables

```
SELECT A.column1, B.column1
 FROM table1 A 
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 B
ON A.column1=B.column1
```

This will give you all results on the table but will show null values where it is in one but not the other.